# DNS Alias in SSRS Subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, reporting

We have an SSRS instance that is widely used, and we use a DNS alias to access the reports.  However, when you create a subscription to a report that sends a link, the server name is given and not the DNS alias.  I never would have noticed this, but in an effort to keep branding consistent, someone recommended that we use the DNS alias here as well.

Anyone know of a way to change that, so that subscriptions use the alias?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else.  If you open Reporting Services Configuration Manager you can specific a URL for the Web Portal. If you use the DNS alias here this automatically sets the subscription emails to have the DNS alias.  The Web Service and Web Portal address have to match and make sure you have your Kerberos/NTLM settings configured properly or you'll get an error when you try to manage subscriptions from the server itself.